# javascript/css: scrollbars w/in a containing div when the nested div gets too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got this html (simplified)

```
<div class="outer" style="float:left">
  <div class="inner" style="float:left">
    <div class="contained" style="clear:both">...</div>
    <div class="contained" style="clear:both">...</div>
    <div class="contained" style="clear:both">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner" style="float:left">
    <div class="contained" style="clear:both">...</div>
    <div class="contained" style="clear:both">...</div>
    <div class="contained" style="clear:both">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the "inner" divs are resizable vis jQuery:

```
$(".contained").resizable({
    maxHeight: "27px"
  });
```

The behavior I'm looking for is to have the "outer" div sprout horizontal scrollbars when one or more of the "inner" divs is resized. Here are the classes on inner and outer in my .css file:

```
.outer {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}

.inner {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Some of those css values are "sacrificing the chicken" things--meaning I was getting desperate and throwing darts at it.

If you need any further details, please let me know.

thanks!

Comment: Can you upload a working example to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please

Comment: why don't you use overflow auto in css ?

Comment: yep, I think so. give me a few minutes...I have to convert my haml to html :P

Comment: Here's the fiddle link, though for some reason it doesn't handle the resizable there...I like that fiddle thing...if nothing else comes of this, that's a hugely cool thing :) so thanks

Comment: @Val, I just tried that and it didn't do the trick. it did make the scrollbars show up but it still grows the outer div rather than scrolling the inner divs with in that one

Comment: Anu has given you a great example I don't understand what do you mean by scrolling...

Comment: oh, sorry, I mean that I was the scrollbar along the bottom of the div that contains the column divs and at the same time I don't want a scroll bar on the side

Comment: argh, one place where my example is unclear above is that I actually float those "inner" divs left so that I end up with 2 divs side by side each having 3 more divs stack on top of each other.

Comment: you should also look up clearfix... which you will help with width and height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want [this behaviour](http://jsfiddle.net/vhapS/)

I used overflow:scroll property on inner div

Comment: with this I end up with scrollbars on each of the inner divs instead of one that they are all inside of...I should go back and read a book on CSS :P I've gotten some good information out of these comments and answer though, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
.outer {
    overflow:auto;
}
```